# Multiple File Upload SWF that returns full path+filename

Tags: c#, javascript, flash, sharepoint-2010

I am in the process of writing a custom script for our internal SharePoint system that will allow for multiple file uploads on list items. In order for this to happen, I was wanting to use a flash file input (to select multiple files at the same time) and then pass an array of file paths (local to the user) into my ASP page to do the actual uploading.

Does anyone know of a SWF multiple upload plugin that allows this? I've looked at Uploadify and cannot find what I need there.

Or, if there is an alternative. Reason I'm wanting local path is so I can pass that into my ASP.NET page to handle the uploading into a SharePoint list item's attachment folder.

Comment: Assume you find something that gives local file path to HTML page (I hope not), how knowing a local path is going to help you with file upload?

Comment: Not sure why you _hope_ I don't find something. A single file input will give you a full path, it's not that unheard of. I've seen people talk about security risks, but what's the point if you can use multiple file inputs and get the path for each file?

The purpose of knowing the local path is so I can pass it through to a method I built that will upload files to a SharePoint list item's attachment folder.

Comment: On "hope" portion - I don't think that Flash/SL will give you path to a local file, and I believe browsers do not return path in non-intranet cases. It is still unclear how you plan to use local path to upload files from HTML page (you need full trust/unsafe for scripting object to do it, so why not to grab file paths there too)?

Comment: This is being built in ASP.NET so it'd be using server side scripting to handle the uploading. It looks like I've been able to find an ashx script for use with Uploadify and have somewhat modified it to work in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Silverlight for this? We had a flash-based multi-upload control based on [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx), but we converted it to Silverlight last year and are much, much happier with that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We are using NeatUpload.
http://neatupload.codeplex.com/

There is not much development going on with it, but it works great and is stable. We've been using it for the last 3 years. But keep in mind that Flash has it's issues and you will have them with all Upload tools that use flash. There is a reason that even Flickr and Wordpress always have an alternative upload link.